Feature selection of binary target from mixed inputs of binary and numerics
I have both binary(0=is not or 1=is) and numerical values in x_train data. The target (y_train) is binary (0=is not or 1=is). What is the best method to do feature selection simultaneously?
I used this code:
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif
x_new = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=8).fit_transform(x_train, y_train)

but I am not sure about correctness of the method.

It is not a question about Python and programming in general. This forum ( https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ )   is a better place for your question.

Also could you please use "code formatting" (triple backtick) for your code snippets.

Thank you Nick! I asked again my question in that forum.

My pleasure. Maybe it is good if you close/delete your question here before someone downvoted/forcibly closed it with "punishment"(?)
